# Amazon S3 Bucket policy, allow only one domain to access files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, same-origin-policy

I have a S3 bucket with a file in it. I only want a certain domain to be able to access the file. I have tried a few policies on the bucket but all are not working, this one is from the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originated from www.example.com and example.com",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.phpfiddle.org/*",
                        "http://phpfiddle.org/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To test the file, i have hosted a code on phpfiddle.org and have this code. But i am not able to access this file neither by directly accessing from the browser nor by the phpfiddle code.

```
<?php 
    $myfile = file_get_contents("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/some-file.txt");
    echo $myfile;
    ?>
```

Here are the permissions for the file, the bucket itself also has the same permissions + the above policy.

[image]

**This is just an example link and not an actually working link.**

Answer (score 5):

The *Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer* bucket policy is only allow your file to be accessed from a page from your domain (the HTTP referrer is your domain).

> Suppose you have a website with domain name (www.example.com or example.com) with links to photos and videos stored in your S3 bucket, examplebucket.

You can't direct access your file from your browser (type directly the file URL into browser). You need to create a link/image/video tag from any page in your domain.

If you want to `file_get_contents` from S3, you need to create a new policy to allow your server IP (see [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3)). Change the IP address to your server IP.

Another solutions is use [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) to download the file into your local. You can also [generate a pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to allow your customer download from S3 directly for a limited time only.